# How can I extract address from query string javascript

Tags: javascript, string

var str = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=**8467**+ **Perimeter**+ **Rd**.+**S**+ **Seattle**+ **Washington**+ **98108**'

from above string How can i extract address from query string javascript.

**8467 Perimeter Rd. S Seattle Washington 98108**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like

```
var reg = /.*addr=([^&]*)/;
var str = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=8467+ Perimeter+ Rd.+S+ Seattle+ Washington+ 98108';
var matches = reg.exec(str);
var address = matches[1].split("+").join(" ");
```

Comment: I would limit the value of `addr` using `([^&]*)`, instead of `(.*)` and use `decodeURI()`, to decode the URI, instead of your `split().join()` implementation.

Comment: Yep, I just edited my post, and then saw your answer :) You're probably right for decodeURI, it was a quick and dirty answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made this crunched down function which acts as an equivalent to PHP's $_GET variable:

```
    function _GET(key, def){

        try{
            return RegExp('[?&]'+key+'=([^?&]*)').exec(location.href)[1]
        }catch(err){
            return !def?'':def
        }

    }
```

this function makes it easily possible to get multiple query strings from the same web address.

```
    //url: 'yoursite.com?f=d&daddr=8467+Perimeter+Rd.+S+Seattle+Washington+98108'

    var SEARCH = _GET('daddr').replace(/[\+]/g, ' ')
    alert(SEARCH)
```